# null is appearing in array, despite checks

Tags: php, arrays, json, null

Seeing some strange behavior coming back when I call up a list of keywords - I get my JSON list but one of the keywords is null, which turns the JSON bad:

```
    "west": [
  "15711989"
],
"work": [
  "15711989"
],
null: [
  "15711992"
],
"€": [
  "15711992"
],
"上水": [
  "15711170"
```

I started running a few checks while doing the loop, but none of them are catching it:

```
if (!is_numeric($keyword) && $keyword != "" && $keyword != " " && $keyword !== NULL && $keyword != "null") {
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding `var_dump($keyword)` inside your loop, to see what the actual value of that $keyword is.

Comment: Thanks @andrewsi - that suggestion worked a treat.  Turned out to be a malformed piece of code (&#160;) that the keyword analysis engine couldn't parse.

Comment: You should add that as an answer, in that case; and accept it when you can.